# How is the Full Standard Model group representation displayed?

Tags: symmetry, standard-model, group-representations

I have often seen, on YouTube lectures and textbooks,  the direct product gauge group representation  listed below and it is often accompanied with a statement to the effect that "this is how we sum up the standard model":

$$SU(3) × SU(2) × U(1)$$

My question is: As the above only deals with the gauge boson side of things, **(SEE ANSWER BELOW)** then is presumably (much) larger group representation that covers **all** of the elements of each of the 3 generations, including quarks and leptons (and the Higgs),  how they interact, how their properties are related, etc, displayed?

In short, is there a  group that represents/combines everything that we know about both fermions and bosons, that we can mathematically express in group representation form.

My usual disclaimer, if you can point me to a website X or textbook Y, that is as good as an answer and hopefully I can come back with better understanding and a better question.

Also, if I have, not surprisingly,  got something badly mixed up, either in concepts,  mangled terminology, or how groups actually work in practice, please just tell me that and   I will delete this question and come back to it later with more background covered.

Comment: Did you look at supersymmetry?

Comment: "is there a group that represents.." do you mean a simple group, e.g. $SU(5)$ GUT? if not, what you've already written is such a group

Comment: @innisfree as I asked in my comment to Anna, by analogy with the brevity of the Einstein equation, where a large amount of information is contained within one short line and has to be "unpacked" to be worked with, I wondered if all of the SM is contained within the gauge group in the OP. Obviously my background is not up to it right now but I think my mistake was taking the  wording "gauge groups" literally to mean just bosons, but if it covers much more than that when "expanded", that's ok,I will need to read more and have a better prepared question later. Thanks very much.

Comment: Bear in mind that those groups really need subscripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As the above only deals with the gauge boson side of things

This is a wrong assumption.

The format represents the total knowledge from innumerable data of particle physics that have been fitted with  SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) . The particles are slotted into representations of the groups and there are rules of how the interactions happen within the structure of the groups. There exists a standard model [lagrangian](http://einstein-schrodinger.com/Standard_Model.pdf)  and the groups are a symmetry of this lagrangian. For an example how the known particles are within a representation [see this.](http://pdg.web.cern.ch/pdg/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-su3-isoscalar-factors.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Anna,I had seen the langranian before and I appreciate the necessity of condensing it. For example the Dirac equation looks tiny using slash notation but hides matrices.  Is the expression in my OP analogous to say the Einstein equation in GR, in that for brevity it can be written using say 12 symbols but then to work on it requires expanding it into 10 coupled inhomogenous p.d.equations?

Comment: Its also nice to talk frequently about what subscripts one might see attached to these group names like L for left handed, Y for hypercharge, and C for color charge

Comment: I don't think it is a wrong assumption - the SM gauge group does only specify the gauge bosons, it doesn't specify the representations of the fermions. a priori you could have the SM gauge group but all the fermions could be singlets

Comment: @innisfree The standard model is the standard model because it has not only the gauge bosons but also the triplets, octuplets and decuplets etc in which all the plethora of particles and resonances are slotted. You did not look at the link in the answer, by which the feynman diagrams are drawn for the interactions describing crossections see also this http://physics.lbl.gov/shapiro/Physics226/lecture7.pdf  .

Comment: i don't want to look at any of those links. the group $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ doesn't specify the SM - you need to specify how many fermions and scalars there are, and what reps they're in.

Comment: @innisfree I do not disagree with your last. Gauge bosons are not enough, you have to put the quarks and leptons in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg . The groups are the symmetry of the Lagrangian, and characterize it as a short hand.

Comment: right, so it isn't a "wrong assumption" that $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ only really specifies the gauge bosons...

Comment: @innisfree  Yes , it is wrong. Gauge bosons could exist in other groups, SU(5) or what not. The reason the specific groups were chosen was because of the measured / observed data that could be most economically ( and not with a plethora of not seen resonances and particles )slotted into SU(3*SU(2)xU(1) representations